# How to find all SQL Agent Jobs that call a given stored-proc

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, agent

I'm in SQL 2008/R2.  I want to run a query to see if there is a SQL Agent job calling a specified stored proc (there are too many to inspect manually).

Comment: this page have all  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/

Comment: Install RedGate SQL Search tool in SSMS. It's free and makes a lot of things a breeze.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here is a query that will give you that and more (look at the `WHERE` clause for the stored proc name):

```
SELECT
    [sJOB].[job_id] AS [JobID]
    , [sJOB].[name] AS [JobName]
    , [sJSTP].[step_uid] AS [StepID]
    , [sJSTP].[step_id] AS [StepNo]
    , [sJSTP].[step_name] AS [StepName]
    , CASE [sJSTP].[subsystem]
        WHEN 'ActiveScripting' THEN 'ActiveX Script'
        WHEN 'CmdExec' THEN 'Operating system (CmdExec)'
        WHEN 'PowerShell' THEN 'PowerShell'
        WHEN 'Distribution' THEN 'Replication Distributor'
        WHEN 'Merge' THEN 'Replication Merge'
        WHEN 'QueueReader' THEN 'Replication Queue Reader'
        WHEN 'Snapshot' THEN 'Replication Snapshot'
        WHEN 'LogReader' THEN 'Replication Transaction-Log Reader'
        WHEN 'ANALYSISCOMMAND' THEN 'SQL Server Analysis Services Command'
        WHEN 'ANALYSISQUERY' THEN 'SQL Server Analysis Services Query'
        WHEN 'SSIS' THEN 'SQL Server Integration Services Package'
        WHEN 'TSQL' THEN 'Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)'
        ELSE sJSTP.subsystem
      END AS [StepType]
    , [sPROX].[name] AS [RunAs]
    , [sJSTP].[database_name] AS [Database]
    , [sJSTP].[command] AS [ExecutableCommand]
    , CASE [sJSTP].[on_success_action]
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Quit the job reporting success'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Quit the job reporting failure'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Go to the next step'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Go to Step: ' 
                    + QUOTENAME(CAST([sJSTP].[on_success_step_id] AS VARCHAR(3))) 
                    + ' ' 
                    + [sOSSTP].[step_name]
      END AS [OnSuccessAction]
    , [sJSTP].[retry_attempts] AS [RetryAttempts]
    , [sJSTP].[retry_interval] AS [RetryInterval (Minutes)]
    , CASE [sJSTP].[on_fail_action]
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Quit the job reporting success'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Quit the job reporting failure'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Go to the next step'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Go to Step: ' 
                    + QUOTENAME(CAST([sJSTP].[on_fail_step_id] AS VARCHAR(3))) 
                    + ' ' 
                    + [sOFSTP].[step_name]
      END AS [OnFailureAction]
FROM
    [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] AS [sJSTP]
    INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS [sJOB]
        ON [sJSTP].[job_id] = [sJOB].[job_id]
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] AS [sOSSTP]
        ON [sJSTP].[job_id] = [sOSSTP].[job_id]
        AND [sJSTP].[on_success_step_id] = [sOSSTP].[step_id]
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] AS [sOFSTP]
        ON [sJSTP].[job_id] = [sOFSTP].[job_id]
        AND [sJSTP].[on_fail_step_id] = [sOFSTP].[step_id]
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysproxies] AS [sPROX]
        ON [sJSTP].[proxy_id] = [sPROX].[proxy_id]
WHERE [sJSTP].[command] LIKE '%MyStoredProc%'
ORDER BY [JobName], [StepNo]
```

Credit should go to the article [Querying SQL Server Agent Job Information](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/) by Dattatrey Sindol for most of the above query.

Comment: Its giving me this error `The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobs', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.`

Answer (score 21):

You can use this query -

```
SELECT s.step_id,
       j.[name],
       s.database_name,
       s.command
FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS s
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j ON  s.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE  s.command LIKE '%Stored_procedure%'
```

Comment: This works with sql server 2000(not a typo), can search for stored procedure executed

Answer (score 2):

There's alternative to find all procedures called by all jobs inside a specific instance:

```
SELECT jss.jobname, jss.step_name, p.name  FROM sys.procedures p 

CROSS apply
(
    SELECT j.name AS jobname, js.step_name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js 
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON js.job_id=j.job_id
    WHERE js.command LIKE '%'+p.name+'%'
) jss
```