# Query to list the job names and step associated with a particular table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

Is there any way to search and find ,what job holds a particular table refresh .
There are multiple sql agent jobs with multiple steps.What is the sql query to search all jobs and locate the job name and steps?

This is to identify the steps associated with a table load

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/14524/get-a-list-of-sql-server-agent-jobs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all SQL Agent Jobs that call a given stored-proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105547/how-to-find-all-sql-agent-jobs-that-call-a-given-stored-proc)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at this:

[Querying SQL Agent Jobs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/)

```
use msdb

SELECT 
    [sJOB].[job_id] AS [JobID]
    , [sJOB].[name] AS [JobName]
    ,step.step_name
    ,step.command
FROM
    [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS [sJOB]
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].dbo.sysjobsteps step ON sJOB.job_id = step.job_id

WHERE step.command LIKE '%MYTABLENAME%'
ORDER BY [JobName]
```